# I can't read info in my static tableview cells

Tags: swift, uitableview

i've created a static tableview in my app, with tens sections. every cell is custom, with three labels that contain information. I wish to read this information.
Is there any way to read these informations? I try everything but nothing, no result. Since i've no array and no datasource, I don't know how to use delegate method.

thanx 
Sergio

Comment: Why? You have these informations in your model, reading them from the cells shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate all your `UITableViewCells` through code to read the `UILabel` information.

```
for (var j = 0; j < yourTableView.numberOfSections(); ++j){

    for (var i = 0; i < yourTableView.numberOfRowsInSection(j); ++i){

         var cellItem = yourTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: j))

         var subviews = cellItem!.contentView.subviews

         for subview : AnyObject in subviews{

            if subview.isKindOfClass(UILabel){

                 var labeItem = subview as! UILabel

                 print(labeItem.text) // make use of Tag property to identify the labels
            }
       }

    }
}
```

Implement the below code, If you wish to read only when user select a row

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        var cellItem = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

        var subviews = cellItem!.contentView.subviews

        for subview : AnyObject in subviews{

            if subview.isKindOfClass(UILabel){

                var labeItem = subview as! UILabel

                print(labeItem.text) // make use of Tag property to identify the labels
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: where i have to insert this code? in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: you can put it anywhere in your code after loaded the tableview.

Comment: where do you exactly want to read this info? when clicking on the row?

Comment: yes, when i select a row, i wish read the content of one of my three labels in that cell.

Comment: ok. i implement your code, nothing, When I see debug,  I noted that the subview in iteration is never label type, but UIView -> UIResponder. The code doesn't find any label. :(

Comment: I have updated the answer. Modified the line as var subviews = cellItem!.contentView.subviews. Please check the latest answer. This will work!

Comment: great! work perfectly. You are wonderfull, many many many THANX